# Docker enable VirtioFS via config file

Tags: docker, config, settings

Is there any way to enable VirtioFS settings for Docker via config file?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT5F3.png)

Answer (score 2):

While not directly answering your question, I found a way to check if it is enabled at least.

The Docker Desktop settings file has a line that indicates if VirtioFS is enabled or not:

> "useVirtualizationFrameworkVirtioFS": true,

The settings file depends on the OS, where is the location for Mac and Linux:

```
case "$( uname )" in
  Darwin)
    settings="~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json"
    ;;
  Linux)
    settings="~/.docker/desktop/settings.json"
    ;;
esac
```

Changing the setting manually didn't work (it get stuck on "Starting")

Comment: Thanks for that. My Docker wasn't starting after I enabled the VirtioFS, and I was able to disable it in the config, fixing the problem.

Comment: Same boat. Enabling VirtioFS stops Docker from booting, you have to disable it in settings.json for it to work again...